# Sticky mac learning PC mac as vlan voice on Cisco 3750v2

Tags: cisco, port-security

I have port security configured as follows:

```
 switchport access vlan 196
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 3
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
```

And on the jack is a Dell Computer. Twice this week the user has called the Help Desk complaining that they don't have network access and both times I discovered that sticky had learned her mac address as "vlan voice" (no voice vlan is configured) as shown:

```
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky xxxx.xxxx.xxxx vlan voice
```

If I simply clear sticky on this port it relearns it as "vlan access" and everything is fine (at least for a day or so). Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does she use cisco's softphone?

Comment: What version of code on the 3750?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before, I think it was on a soft phone.  Anyways the fix was disabling cdp on the port.

```
(config-if)#no cdp enable
```